# EXTJS - Load Mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4.2

I want to present the source code, which is taken from inside a div with jQuery, inside an `Ext.Window`. I have managed to do that, but my problem is that sometimes the source code is huge, since it contains encoded images and the `Ext.Window` takes some time to appear in the screen after it is triggered via click event. I would like to present the `Ext.Window` but with a loading icon until the data is ready.

```
win = new Ext.Window ({
    title:'Source Code',
    width:800,
    height:300,
    items: [{
        xtype : 'textarea',
        readOnly: true,
        value: sourceCode
    }]
});
win.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a undefined function and a setTimeout function. Do not forget the config layout: 'fit'.

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
       var win =  Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title:'Source Code',
            width:800,
            height:300,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype : 'textarea',
                readOnly: true,
                value: 'test'
            }]
        });


        win.show(undefined, function(){
            win.getEl().mask('Loading...');

            setTimeout(function() {
                win.getEl().unmask();
            }, 3000);

        });
    }

});
```

Or

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
   Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title:'Source Code',
        width:800,
        height:300,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype : 'textarea',
            readOnly: true,
            value: 'test'
        }]
    }).show(undefined, function(){
        win.getEl().mask('Loading...');

        setTimeout(function() {
            win.getEl().unmask();
        }, 3000);

     });
  }

});
```

TRY

```
    win.show(undefined, function(){
        win.getEl().mask('Loading...');
        win.suspendEvents();
        win.down('textarea').setValue(sourceCode);
        win.down('textarea').focus();
        win.resumeEvents();
        setTimeout(function() {
            win.getEl().unmask();
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer josei, now i can see the masking but again the window will appear after a while and the timeout will start after the window is appeared..

Comment: I have managed to do it by using your first block of code and setting the item value in the timeout function instead of the window constructor . win.items.items[0].setValue(sourceCode); If you want edit your answer so i can accept it as correct !

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is to set the value only after the window is already displayed:

```
win = new Ext.Window ({
    title:'Source Code',
    width:800,
    height:300,
    items: [{
        xtype : 'textarea',
        readOnly: true
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(sourceWindow) {
            sourceWindow.down('textarea').setValue(sourceCode)
        }
    }
});
win.show();
```

Then you can add josei's mask/unmask approach on top of that, although I would recommend that you search some event that happens after the value has been set to remove the mask (you can try the `change` event on the textarea), because that way your wait wouldn't be a fixed amount of time, but related to the time it takes to render the textarea value.

Comment: Unfortunately with this approach, the window will not appear until the sourceCode is ready.